# How do I correctly create a related object overriding the save() method?

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

I'm overriding the `save()` method on a subclass of a UserCreationForm. I'm doing so because I'd like to create another related object as the User object is created.
Here is the form along with the save method:

```
class MyUserCreationForm(UserCreationForm):

    error_message = UserCreationForm.error_messages.update({
        'duplicate_username': 'This username has already been taken.'
    })

    class Meta(UserCreationForm.Meta):
        model = User

    def clean_username(self):
        username = self.cleaned_data["username"]
        try:
            User.objects.get(username=username)
        except User.DoesNotExist:
            return username
        raise forms.ValidationError(self.error_messages['duplicate_username'])

    def save(self, commit=True):
        user = super(MyUserCreationForm, self).save(commit=False)
        if commit:
            user.save()
            Profile.objects.create(user=user)
        return user
```

So the `Profile` object is never created. I can get it to work, technically, if I remove the `if commit:` like so:

```
    def save(self, commit=True):
        user = super(MyUserCreationForm, self).save(commit=False)
        user.save()
        Profile.objects.create(user=user)
        return user
```

However I'd like to know why `False` is being passed to the `save()` method each time I create a User. Based on what I've read, the conditional should be there in order to preserve the same behavior as the overridden `save()` method.

Comment: Could you raise an exception in the save method to find what's calling it? From what I've found in the Django documentation, there's no reason to check for the commit value unless you'd like to do post-processing on the object before you've saved it to the database.

Comment: @DanLoewenherz, I receive a `'NoneType' object has no attribute 'save'`. With the conditional code, the code will go through the initial `super()` call, but not get through the `if commit`

Comment: I believe the problem is in the fact that this is for the django admin. I mistakenly(?) thought that the code in any subclass of the UserCreationForm would apply to all new User instances. But it seems only to apply to the admin in this context. Still, I'm curious why there's no `commit`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Where is this form being used? If it's in a `ModelAdmin` for example, it might be because `ModelAdmin` has its own `save_model` method.

```
def save_model(self, request, obj, form, change):
    """
    Given a model instance save it to the database.
    """
    obj.save()
```

Since this is where the model is  intended to be saved, I'm going to assume that `commit` is `False` so that it can be done here.

You could try overriding this in your `ModelAdmin`, for example, but it depends where this is being used. Dan Loewenherz is correct, you shouldn't really use the `commit` check for stuff like this. Generally, it's really more for use with the *form*, whereas this is a problem focused around your *model*.

The problem here I think is the pattern you're using. I think it's better to keep the purpose of the Form more closely tied to the model itself.

What happens if later on, a user is created using a different method or form? They will lack a `Profile`. I'm assuming this is the common User/User Profile problem that comes from the limitations of the built in auth user model in which case a `User` without a `Profile` could be disastrous.

My recommendation would be to use a `post_save` signal in `models.py`:

```
from django.db.models.signals import post_save
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from models import UserProfile
from django.db import models

def create_profile(sender, instance, created **kwargs):
    if created:
        Profile.objects.create(user = instance)

post_save.connect(create_profile, sender = User, dispatch_uid = "users-
profilecreate-signal")
```

Some people are hesitant to use signals, but they are the most reliable way to preserve the integrity of your model in a case like this.

The other option would be to do it at the model level on the `User`. Something like this:

```
def save(self, *args, *kwargs):
    user = super(User, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
    Profile.objects.get_or_create(user = user)
    return user
```

Answer (score 2):

`commit=False` is meant to be used in inline forms. It's used to assign the parent key to the form instance and save the instance later on.

Source: https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/forms/models.py#L942

You should be able to adjust your solution a little bit.

```
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    user = super(MyUserCreationForm, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
    if user.pk:  # If user object has been saved to the db
        Profile.objects.get_or_create(user=user)
    return user
```

But I recommend to use Django's model signals.

```
from django.db.models.signals import post_save
from django.dispatch import receiver

@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def user_created_signal_handler(request, user, *args, **kwargs):
    Profile.objects.get_or_create(user=user)
```

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/signals/#django.db.models.signals.post_save